# Prevent spinner from reacting on pageup and pagedown key

Tags: jquery-ui, spinner, keyboard-events

I use a jquery ui spinner in a tabbed dialog. I have attached a keydown handler to the window object, so that the user can switch to the next tab by pressing the page down key and to the previous tab by pressing page up, respectively.

Now the problem is that the spinner is the first control in its tab and thus gets focus when the tab becomes active. When the user presses the page up key to switch to the next tab, the keystroke also changes the spinner's value.

What would be the most elegant way to prevent the spinner from reacting to pageup/-down keystrokes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inititialized the spinner with the option "page" set to 0. That way, the keydown handler of the spinner is still triggered, but the spinner's value doesn't change anymore. So, this is not exactly what I asked for, but the effect is the same.